# Linq2Sql, GroupBy and return specific object

Tags: linq-to-sql, group-by

I'm have a list of keywords;

- pizza (10:13 PM)
- milk (10:12 PM)
- pizza (10:11 PM)
- pizza (10:10 PM)
- milk (10:09 PM)
- beans (10:08 PM)
- corn (10:07 PM)
- juice (10:06 PM)
- foo (10:05 PM)

I want to group them like this (top 5, notice foo is not in the list):

- Pizza (3) (10:13 PM)
- Milk (2) (10:12 PM)
- Beans (1) (10:08 PM)
- Corn (1) (10:07 PM)
- Juice (1) (10:06 PM)

So basically: list keywords after date created, grouped by keyword and .Take(5). And how is this possible using lambda expressions? And how to return them as object of a specific type? Let's say type `LatestSearch`.

**UPDATE**
Ended up with this query:

```
var searches = db.Searches
             .GroupBy(s => s.Keyword)
             .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedDate).First())
             .OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedDate)
             .Take(5);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `after date created`?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
table.Where(s => whatever)
     .GroupBy(s => s.Keyword)
     .Select(g => new { 
         Keyword = g.OrderByDescending(s => s.Date),
         Count = g.Count(),
         Date = g.Max(s => s.Date())
      })
     .OrderByDescending(s => s.Count)
     .Take(5);
```

**EDIT**: If you only want an `IEnumerable<LatestSearch>`, write the following:

```
table.Where(s => whatever)
     .GroupBy(s => s.Keyword)
     .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
     .Select(g => g.First());
     .Take(5);
```

Comment: Thank you, for the answer, SLaks. I've updated my question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Looks like what I'm looking for! But how do I return them as IEnumerable<LatestSearch>?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to order by Count(), but .CreatedDate :-)